# How can I filter data in a Razor view with a dropdown

Tags: c#, html, razor, model-view-controller

Hello I'm new to MVC and I'm trying to do a filtering for my index page, I want to be able to filter the graduation Status.

So when I go into the index I will see every status and I want to filter for example only the person with the graduated Status or the Pass/failed Status

Thank you in advance!

[Index Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bgSs.png)

Controller:

```
        var graduates = db.Graduated_Students;
        return View(graduates.ToList());
```

View:

```
    <div class="content-body">
             <div class="row">
                 <form action="#" method="post">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-12">

                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Resource.FirstName
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Resource.LastName
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Resource.CohortNumber
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Placements
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Resource.GraduationStatus
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
                                          item.FirstName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
                                             item.LastName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
                                            item.PartnerName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
                                 item.GraduationStatus)
                            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use linq in the View to filter the data

**In the View**

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(t=> t.GraduationStatus == <the graduation status selected in the dropdown> );
```

*This approach Gets all the data from the database and then performs the filtering*

That approach would work however a better approach would be to send the Selected GraduationStatus to the controller as a parameter and then perform the filtering directly on the db variable

**In the Controller**

```cs
public IActionResult GeStudents(GraduationStatus selectedGraduationStatus) 
{
    var graduates = db.Graduated_Students.Where(t=> t.GraduationStatus == selectedGraduationStatus);
    return View(graduates.ToList());
}
```

*This way you don't get all of the students from the database but only the ones which match the filter*

Comment: Thanks for the help !! what do you mean should I enter in this ? : <the graduation status selected in the dropdown>

Comment: the selected graduated status variable from the dropdown.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work... I'm probably doing something wrong here